# Irreducibility of a particular surface in Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry Exercise 2.1.14.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The exercise is quoted from Shafarevich's book.

> **14.** For what values of $a$ does the curve $F(x_0,x_1,x_2):=x_0^3+x_1^3+x_2^3+a\left(x_0+x_1+x_2\right)^3=0$ have a singular
> point? What are its singular points then? Is it reducible?

I was able to show that the curve has a singular point at $(1:1:1)$ when $a=-\frac{1}{9}$ (working in characteristic $\neq 3$). This came out to be a medium length argument on manipulating equations. However, I am struggling with the question regarding reducibility.

My suspicion is that it is irreducible. My thought is that I should define a regular map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ from this curve to another projective variety which is surjective, the fibres are irreducible, and $Y$ is irreducible. Then I can appeal to Theorem II.1.26 in Shafarevich. However, I cannot come up with a reasonable map since I would need injectivity for this to work.

This should be a very basic question so a hint should suffice for my satisfaction.

Comment: Over a field of characteristic $3$ it follows $F(x_0,x_1,x_2)=(1+a)(x_0+x_1+x_2)^3$ which is non reduced, hence every point is singular.

Comment: Good point. I was implicitly working characteristic $\neq 3$ with my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let $s_1=x_0+x_1+x_2$, $s_2=x_0x_1+x_1x_2+x_2x_0$, $s_3=x_0x_1x_2$. Then you may write $$F=(a+1)s_1^3-3s_1s_2+3s_3$$

Comment: Just to make sure I got the right idea -- so $F$ is written where $s_i$'s are symmetric polynomials. Irreducibility in $k[s_1,s_2,s_3]$ is clear since there is the $s_3$ linear factor. A factorization in $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ leads to a contradiction because if it factorized, there is a linear term $ax_0+bx_1+cx_2$. Then consider the action of $S_3$. This gives $3$ conjugates to this linear factor. So it is stabilized by some transposition i.e. WLOG $ax_0+bx_1$ is the linear factor with $a,b$ nonzero. But this cannot be because $x_0^3,x_1^3,x_2^3$ all appear